# Search not rendering excerpt (or full text)

Tags: search

anyone ever run into an issue with the simple search form where it won't render the excerpt or the full text?  I'm using the simple search form from the search module (EE module, not a 3rd party) ... I'm getting results with the title of pages but nothing more.

Comment: Have you set the excerpt fields in the channel preferences?

Answer (score 2):

Have you checked the option to make your field searchable? go to admin > channel administration > channel fields and select the group and field you want to show up in results and make sure its searchable.

see attached screenshot.

[image]

Comment: yes, i did ... i actually was able to fix this by going into channel preferences and simply resaving the preference page.  weird.

Comment: glad to hear you got it working. Strange that you had to do that though.

Comment: it was weird - haven't had that happen before but sometimes the simple fix is overlooked!  was digging around in code and settings before just trying this on a whim.